# How to resolve Uncaught Type error $().barcode is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).barcode is not a function
    at codeBars (bookingAdd.php:152)
    at Object.success (bookingAdd.php:141)
    at fire (VM88 jquery-1.10.2.js:3048)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM88 jquery-1.10.2.js:3160)
    at done (VM88 jquery-1.10.2.js:8235)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (VM88 jquery-1.10.2.js:8778)
codeBars @ bookingAdd.php:152
success @ bookingAdd.php:141
fire @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3160
done @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8235
callback @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8778
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8136
bookingSlipAjax @ bookingAdd.php:99
(anonymous) @ bookingAdd.php:782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the jquery-barcode.js is linked properly and after that check the way you print the code number.

example -

```
        <?php $barcode = "152294018467"; ?>
        <link href="/assets/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery-barcode.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.barcode-block').barcode("<?php echo $barcode; ?>", "ean13");
            });
        </script>

        <div class="barcode-block"></div>
```